# How to get the 2nd last row inserted using time?

Tags: sql, oracle

When a user logs in to my application the row is inserted in the login log table. I want the last login time to be printed when user logs in to the system. How can I get the last login time?

I've tried `max(time)`, but it gives me the current login time, but I want the previous. How can I get this?

Here is my query:

```
select login_time
from tblname
where emp_code = 123
  and login_time = (select max(LOGIN_TIME)
                    from tblname
                    where emp_code = 123)
```

Comment: Please tag the correct dbms. Is it MySQL, Oracle, or SQL Server?

Comment: Something like: select max(login_time) from ... where login_time < current_time?

Comment: no,it's not the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOGIN_TIME DESC) AS rn
    FROM tblname
    WHERE emp_code = 123
)
SELECT LOGIN_TIME FROM CTE WHERE rn = 2
```

---

Without using a CTE:

```
SELECT LOGIN_TIME 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOGIN_TIME DESC) AS rn
    FROM tblname
    WHERE emp_code = 123
) t
WHERE rn = 2
```

---

You could also make use of Oracle's `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT login_time
    FROM tblname
    WHERE emp_code = 123
    ORDER BY login_time DESC
) t
WHERE ROWNUM = 2
```

Comment: suggest me the answer without using 'with cte",just a simple query

Comment: Just move the query in the cte to a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a WHERE Subquery like so:

`SELECT MAX(login_time)
    FROM tblname
    WHERE emp_code=123 AND 
         login_time NOT IN
           (SELECT MAX(login_time)
            FROM tblname
            WHERE emp_code=123
           )`